# Global variables in Python?

Tags: python, global

I have a question about global variables in python.
If I got this correctly, all variables that I define in my class can be read from each method in this class.
Now I thought that I could only write into the global variables if I mark them with global 'variableName' before. But here is what freaks me out:

```
def foo(a):
    for i in range(a[0].__len__()):
        a[0][i] -= a[1][i]
a = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
foo(a)
print(a)
```

gives me

```
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

But WHY? I mean, I never decleared 'global a'.

Strange thing is, if i do:

```
def foo(a):
    a -= 1
a = 2
foo(a)
print(a)
```

Why does this give me

```
2
```

I don't understand the difference :/

Comment: FYI `x.__len__()` is idiomatically written `len(x)`.

Comment: i know that ;) i also like your way better, but my teacher wants me to do it this way.

Comment: read this
["pass variable by reference"][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a problem with your function definitions. You are passing both functions an argument, thus making it unnecessary to declare anything global in the first place. If you would remove the arguments from your definitions, this question would make a little more sense.

The whole confusion here lies within mutability of data types in python. Lists and dictionaries are mutable containers, which means that their values can be changed at any time. Other data types, like integers, floats, tuples and so on are immutable. You cannot change them. You can create new ones, like `1 + 1` will return a new integer `2`.

In your first example, you're modifying the contents of a list. Lists are mutable containers which means that their contents can change. If you happen to have `a` in the global scope, then a function in that same scope *can* modify the contents of the list.

```
def foo():
    """ Notice i've removed the argument `a` from the function def, to illustrate my point.. """
    for i in range(a[0].__len__()):
        a[0][i] -= a[1][i]
>>> a = [[0,1,2,3,4,5,6],[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]]
>>> foo()
>>> print(a)
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

In your second example, you're modifying an integer. Integers are immutable data types and cannot be modified. The following *will* modify the variable `a` (by creating a new integer) in the local scope of function `foo()` but because you have not defined `a` global or return the local `a`, there's no visible change.

```
def foo(a):
    a -= 1
>>> a = 2
>>> foo(a)
>>> print(a)
2
```

Comment: thanks for your help, this seems to make sense.
but is there a way to hand over the list object and not make it change in the global namespace? i think no, right? :/

Comment: In your example you're modifying the list *in place*. It's often better to generate an entirely new list.

Comment: ok, thank you. this is what i originally tried to circumvent. but i will do it like this ;)

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR `global` is not about mutability.

You're passing a list to the function as the argument `a`. A list is mutable, so the function can change it. The fact that the argument and the global are both called `a` is immaterial:

```
def foo(some_list):
    some_list.append('foo!')

global_list = []

foo(global_list)
print(global_list)
```

prints `['foo!']` even though `foo` doesn't reference `global_list` directly. The same is happening in your code.

Now more to the point wrt. modifying globals:

```
def bar():
    global_list.append('bar.')
```

will also modify `global_list`, because when it looks up the symbol `"global_list"` it finds it in the module ("global") scope. The only case where you need the `global` keyword is when you want to rebind the *name* `global_list`, because in

```
def reset():
    global_list = []
```

the assignment implicitly creates a local variable `global_list`, so it should be written

```
def reset():
    global global_list
    global_list = []
```